# jquery mobile select fo fill remaining space

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How can I make a select fill the whole screen while surrounded by two fixed width buttons within a button group?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <ul data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <li><button type="submit">&lt;</button></li>

        <li><select name="select-mes" id="select-mes">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        </select></li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit">&gt;</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This creates a small button bar aligned to the left. I want the select in the middle to fill the remaining space (which would be variable depennding on the screen)

A fiddle with my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kelmer/kq1r33nz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to your HTML structure.

```
<div class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <button type="submit">&lt;</button>
            <select name="select-mes" id="select-mes">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit">&gt;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First, add `display: table` to *controlgroup*  inner wrapper `.ui-controlgroup-controls`. For the inner elements, make them `table-cell` by adding `display: table-cell` and removing floating `float: left`.

```css
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls > * {
   display: table-cell;
   float: none !important;
}

.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-select {
    width: 100%; /* let selectmenu occupy available width */
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bobj5fs7/)** with `ui-field-contain` wrapping *controlgroup*
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c6tq6up5/)** without `ui-field-contain`

Comment: @sergioFC hmmm, honestly I didn't check it in FF. maybe a _vendor_ prefix is missing. I'll check it out :)

Comment: @sergioFC http://www.carsonshold.com/2014/07/css-display-table-cell-child-width-bug-in-firefox-and-ie/

Comment: + 1 as it's related to a firefox buggy behaviour.

Comment: @sergioFC even `table-layout: fixed` doesn't fix the issue. I'm still trying to find a workaround for FF and IE. I'll let you know. _Que tengas un buen dia_ :)